# Pass a list of values in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code where I am passing a list of values:

```
    var message = new List<XYZ>()
    {
       new XYZ
       {
         EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = ccEmailAddress }
       }
    };
```

In the above code, **ccEmailAddress** is a list of strings. For example, consider ccEmailAddress contains ‘n’ values:

```
var ccEmailAddress = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "abc@yahoo.com",
                        "pqr@yahoo.com"                  
                    };
```

How do I pass ‘n’ XYZ objects to **message**? (‘n’ can vary)

```
    var message = new List<XYZ>()
    {
       new XYZ
       {
         EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address =   "abc@yahoo.com" }
       },

new XYZ
       {
         EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address =     "pqr@yahoo.com" }
       }

    };
```

Comment: Have a look at the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0)  about ```List<T>``` especially the class methods like ```Add``` and ```AddRange```

Comment: Your code currently works just fine. Can you please explain what it is that isn't working in that code?

Comment: To clarify, given `public class XYZ { public EmailAddress EmailAddress; } public class EmailAddress { public List<string> Address; }` your current code works just fine. What issue do you actually have?

Comment: _"How do I pass both the strings in the list to message?"_ -- it's not clear what you mean by that. The `message` object can only contain `XYZ` objects, not `string` objects. So taken literally, you _can't_ "pass" the strings to `message` (if by "pass" you mean add them to the list). But on the other hand, the two strings are already part of the `ccEmailAddress` list which is referenced by the `EmailAddress` object that the new `XYZ` object references, so they are already _reachable_ through the `message` reference. You just need to dereference the `XYZ` object, then the `EmailAddress` object

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you!

Comment: I've voted to re-open, but in the meanwhile what you need is this: `List<XYZ> message = ccEmailAddress.Select(a => new XYZ() { Address = a }).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
List<XYZ> message =
    ccEmailAddress
        .Select(a => new XYZ() { Address = a })
        .ToList();
```